# Encrypting/Decrypting using RSA and AES; standards?

Tags: python, bash, unix, encryption, cryptography

I'm looking for a standard way of encrypting and signing a message using RSA and AES.  I understand that in pseudo code the actions taking place are like this:

Alice's actions for sending a secret, signed message to Bob:

```
AES = random()      
message' = encrypt(message, AES)
AES' = encrypt(AES, Bob's public RSA)   
messageHash = hash(message')
signature = encrypt(messageHash, Alice's private RSA)
send(Bob, AES')
send(Bob, message')
send(Bob, signature)
```

Bob's actions for receiving a secret, signed message from Alice:

```
AES', message', signature = split(input)
AES = decrypt(AES', Bob's private RSA)
messageHash = decrypt(signature, Alice's public RSA)
receivedMessageHash = hash(message')
messageHash == receivedMessageHash? --> bail out if unequal
message = decrypt(message', AES)
```

So, Alice chooses a random AES key, encrypts the message with it and send this to Bob, along with an encrypted version of the AES key to decrypt it and a signature to prove her as originator.

Of course, there are other setups, like sending to multiple people or having no need for a signature or similar, but I'm looking for a kind of setup like this.  Maybe I understand something wrong and my pseudo code above lacks precision or contains a bug.  It just represents my crude understanding of the matter ;-)

I can do all this step by step by myself, using Python libraries like `Crypto` or Unix shell tools like `openssl`.

But I'm looking for a standard way to do this, without worrying myself about how to implement paddings or that `split()` function used in the pseudo code when receiving the message.  I guess there must be a library or a tool set or whatever which does this for me and which maybe even allows to interoperate with other programs doing similar tasks.

Questions:

1. Is my setup described above feasible and typical?  Or does it contain any logical errors, flaws or attackable aspects?
2. Is there a standard format for my use case which I should stick to (some RFC, PKCS, …) in order to keep interoperability with other programs, and if so, which software available as Unix command line tools or as Python libraries is capable of handling this standard?

I'd prefer to stick to RSA and AES with an option of exchanging each with any other chosen algorithm, but solutions for a fixed algorithm set would be welcome as well.

As I said, sending from Alice to Bob is my first approach but being able to send to more than one receiver would we a nice bonus.

Comment: I rephrased my question to emphasize that I'm looking for a standard, not necessarily (but also) for a library implementing it.  I want to know what to stick to, how to do implement my use case; I think this is not really off-topic on SO.  (And of course, if there is a library doing it, I'd be also interested, but that's *not* the primary topic.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`gnupg`](https://www.gnupg.org/) to encrypt and sign whatever you want to send.

Getting cryptography right is *hard*. So basically the first principle of crypto is "don't DIY".

But if you must, watch these tutorials first: [the state of crypto in Python](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r_Pj__qjBvA), [what to do when you need crypto](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0m2ZUS9OH4k), [crypto 101](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3rmCGsCYJF8).

Comment: I considered PGP and GPG before writing my question.  They seemed to overachieve for my usecase and make especially key handling more complicated than I would like it to be.  But maybe biting this sour apple might solve later problems like key exchange from the beginning.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: The reason gnupg seems to be complex is because it does its best to e.g. also protect your keys when they are at rest. Hence keyphrases. There's more to encryption than generating a key and calling AES!

Comment: I want to abstract from other aspects like protecting the keys.  That does not mean I intend to neglect these aspects ;-)

Comment: At this moment, there don't seem to be any successful attacks against full-rounds AES (depending on the mode, of course. Don't use ECB!). Historically cryptography is often not so much broken because of weaknesses in the algorithm but because of the way it was (mis)used. The breaking of the enigma code is a nice example. So the "other aspects" are generally *even more* important than the algorithm itself.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing me to the 'cryptography' project presented in these talks.  I actually missed that up to now and it answers several of my questions.